# Excel - Multiply different intervals in one column with specific number

Tags: excel-formula

I want to multiply
the numbers from 0 to 4999 with 0.5
the numbers from 5000 to 9999 with 0.45
the numbers above 10000 with 0.4
and plot it in a simple 2D line chart.

I assumed that would be rather simple, but I struggle to find a feasible solution. Also is there a way to plot the chart in Excel without filling the values for 10000+ rows?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your multiplication problem, asusming your numbers to multiply are in column A and start in A1, input the following in B2 and drag down to get your multiplied number:

```
=IF(A1>=10000,A1*0.4,IF(A1<5000, A1*0.5,A1*0.45))
```

Regarding your plot question, it's hard to help with so little information.

Comment: Thank you for the input. That is exactly what I was looking for. Regarding the plot: is there a way to give Excel the formula and from that formula to specify the interval I want to plot. Like e.g. in GeoGebra where you just type in the formula with variables (x) and can immediately see the plot. Reason is, that I would like to avoid having 10000+ rows of data just to create the plot.

Comment: Excel is not that smart. You need to feed it the data points. However, dragging down/copying a formula (even for 10,000 rows) is not that long. If the answer is what you were looking for, please formally accept as the correct answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Use vlookup and a simple multiply as so:

```
=A1*VLOOKUP(A1,$E$2:$F$4,2,1)
```

[image]

This means it is much easier to change the values used...

Comment: I don't think this would work as OP is asking for a condition based on if the value is in a range of 0 to 49999.

Comment: @PGCodeRider 49999 or 4999, there is a difference, which does the OP give?

Comment: I like the idea :). Also an option: `=A1*VLOOKUP(A1,{0;0.5,5000;0.45,10000;0.4},2,1)`

Comment: Hi and thank you for the help! Exactly as PGSystem Tester said. In this case I would not multiply the first 4999 with 0.5 but also with 0.45 which gives me the incorrect sum (5500*0.45 = 2475). I need the first 4999 records to be multiplied with 0.5 and the 5000th - 9999th with 0.45 and from the 10000th with 0.4.